# Javascript TypeError, can’t access methods of object

Tags: javascript, object, typeerror, p5.js

I am using the p5.js, node.js and socket.io to make a small multiplayer game in the browser. An object called 'player' is passed from one to the other client to sync both clients. This works fine for other code that doesn't rely on method calls. But now that I also want to access methods of stored objects within the player object, it doesn't work anymore.

This would be the object that stores all the variables and the array with objects between the two clients:

```
var player = {
  structures: []
};
```

Now if I add an object called campfire to it like this:

```
player.structures.push(new campfire(mouseX,mouseY));
```

And try to call the draw() method of the object campfire which looks like this:

```
class campfire {
constructor(x,y){
    this.scale = 40;
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.maxLevel = 3;
    this.button = new button(this.x, this.y+50, this.x-50, this.y-70, upgrade, upgrade_hover, this);
    this.show_upgrade_button = true;
}

draw(){
    switch(player.campfire.level){
        case 1: image(fire, this.x, this.y, this.scale, this.scale);break;
        case 2: image(campfire_2, this.x, this.y, this.scale, this.scale);break;
        case 3: image(campfire_3, this.x, this.y, this.scale, this.scale);break;
        default: console.log("cant upgrade, this shouldn't happen.");
    }
    if(this.show_upgrade_button){
        this.button.draw();
    }
}

trigger(){      
    if(player.campfire.level + 1 <= this.maxLevel && this.show_upgrade_button == true){
        this.button.trigger();
    }
}}
```

using

```
player.structures[i].draw();
```

The console (of the client not ushing the object 'campfire' to the array 'structures') prints the following error:

```
gui.js:38 Uncaught TypeError: player.structures[i].draw is not a function
```

The client that is pushing the campfire object to the array is able to make the draw() call and doesn't print an error message. However, the other client that has not pushed the object to the array is not able to use the method and prints out the error, even though they both share the same 'player' object. What's weird is that the one printing out the error is still able to access all variables of the campfire object so it seems to only affect methods.

The only resource I found about this was this article https://airbrake.io/blog/javascript-error-handling/x-is-not-a-function-typeerror
I tried to rename the function to draw = function(){} and campfire.prototype.draw = function(){} but it doesn't make a difference for me. I think the functions are not declared right? That would be the only possible explanation for me right now.

Thank you for the time you took to read my question!

EDIT: here is the link to the project: https://github.com/Mayhoon/Multiplayer-Browsergame

Comment: Are you sure your index `i` is in the range of `0` through to `player.structures.length - 1` ?

Comment: Please, post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @DacreDenny yes, both clients know the length of the array and i can access the objects variables when using player.structures[0].x for example. The for loop i use to iterate over the array does work, but only for the client that is pushing the object to the array.

Comment: Can you post more of the code showing how you populate the structures array, or provide a link to say a github repository?

Comment: @Ele here is the link to the project: https://github.com/Mayhoon/Multiplayer-Browsergame . I use 'nodemon server.js' to start the server on port 3000. You need to have 2 tabs open at the same time. After loading both, press h, click on the image and click on the screen somewhere. The hammer icon is supposed to do the upgrading part and sync the process with the other client when clicked. I only included the nessesary classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is more on a design level. Socket.io (or any other sync library) is not really meant to push entire pieces of code back and forth. In your case that would be the functions of the campfire.

I would advise only pushing `state` back and forth. Does a player have a hammer? How many lives does the player have? Does the player have a campfire? In other words, only sync data that changes constantly.

Since the functionality of the campfire (the draw function) is the same for all players, there is no need to keep pushing that code back and forth every few seconds! It's quite inefficient!

Instead, you can create campfire instances in the client when your sync object says that the player has a campfire.

In code that could look like this (just an idea):

Syncing object for socket.io

```
var player = {
  structures: {campfire:true}
};
```

Client code

```
// create campfire instances, tell the campfire which player it belongs to
if(player.structures.campfire) {
    let cf = new Campfire(player)
    cf.draw()
}
```

*note: it could very well be that socket.io strips out executable code*

Comment: Thank you for your answer, i already did something similiar with the progress bar that is indicating the upgrade process of the campfire and wondered if there would be a better way to do this. I was not sure if this is a javascript problem because the error message suggested it, so i asked here. As you already wrote, it could be that socket.io takes out every method but ill take your advice and just use state variables instead - your answer has helped me a lot, thank you very much!

Comment: Socket IO serializes its objects.During the JSON serialization all methods are gone and only properties are kept.